# Why using the past tense when one parent is dead but the children and the other parent are alive?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

> John met Mary in 2000. He died in 2023. They **had** three children.
> Marc met Ann in 2001. He is alive. They **have** two children.

What are the grammatical reasons for the last verbs to be in past and present tenses when everyone except John is alive?<sup>(1)</sup>

- either the fact that John died should not have an incidence on the children (so Mary and he **have** children)<sup>(2)</sup>
- or we are talking about a fact that happened in the past (childbirth), and then Marc and Ann **had** children
- or is it something else? (such as *"when one person in a group dies, everything they have in common with the group is in the past tense"*)

---

<sup>(1)</sup> example from today's Google Doodle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Chang#Personal_life

<sup>(2)</sup> connected: [They have vs. had three children](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68231/they-have-vs-had-three-children), [What tense should I use when referring to someone's children when some are alive and others dead?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212537/what-tense-should-i-use-when-referring-to-someones-children-when-some-are-alive)

Comment: It's *They **had** three children* in the first example *because "**they**" no longer exist* (as an identifiable unit for syntactic purposes). It's the same as *My husband died last year, but before that **we were** a great team*. You can't say ***we are** a great team* just because *you're* still alive - there is no longer any "we".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - can we not say that my parents 'had' a boy in April 1952, and a girl in January 1955, after my mother died in 1966, even though we were (and are!) both still alive?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sure. But you and your sister aren't the ***subject*** of the verb, so it's syntactically irrelevant whether you're alive or not (even though you being still alive is absolutely central to most contexts where you're referenced! :)

Comment: The phrase is often "They had _#_ children *together*" where "together" means what @FumbleFingers says: when they were a couple.

Comment: ... a consolidated 258,751 points of rep respond in comments while I have my fingers whacked whenever my comment is too "answerish" ... life is unfair ...

Comment: "Why" questions are sometimes like asking "Why is water wet?"  It just is. We can seek to explain why it is reasonable to use the past tense but they're just reasonable explanations.  For all we know, 500 years from now it might have changed to **have**. Part of the answer is formulaic convention.

Comment: @TimR: my "why" was actually a summary of  "what are the grammatical reasons". I will update my question accordingly. FumbleFingers gave a good reason (*they* does not exist, thus the past these when *they* still existed)

Comment: This is not about English, is it? If you translated this into your language, you would face the same issue.

Comment: @Lambie: well, I expect that it depends on the language. In English for instance you would say "Joe Doe **has** died" when informing about his death. In French you would say "Paul Martin **est** mort" (Paul Martin **is** dead)

Comment: @WoJ You may get your fingers whacked on other sites in the network, but ELL is so rife with answers in comments that the community has mostly given up dealing with them. I'd love it if they disappeared, so I encourage users to flag them and I delete every one that's flagged, but if I deleted every answer I found in the comments, I wouldn't have time to answer questions. It's an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dodge the red herring that "have children" can also describe child-bearing. I think your question is more philosophical, about "joint agency" in a plural verb. So what if the example were:

> John met Mary in 2000. He died in 2023. They lived in this town for 10 years. *[And Mary continues to live in this town.]*

Why do we use the past tense for an action that Mary continues? Well, simply because it's "they." *They* lived, *together*, here for 10 years.

> It's *They **had** three children* in the first example because ***"they"*** no longer exist (as an identifiable unit for syntactic purposes). It's the same as *“My husband died last year, but before that we were a great team”*. You can't say ***we are** a great team* just because you're still alive - there is no longer any "we" @FumbleFingers

As FumbleFingers pointed out, other than in a metaphysical sense, "they" do nothing any more, so any sentence with them *both* as the agents must be in past tense, even if a *related* sentence about Mary could be in the present.

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on whether by "having children" you are talking about the past event of giving birth to children, or whether you are talking about the children still existing.

Having children, as in fathering them or giving birth to them, is a single event. A mother might say "*I **had** my son in 1990*", referring to the birth. You would also use 'had' if you were a third party talking about someone else bringing a child into the world in the past, no matter which of the parties may be alive or dead.

If you are speaking about the children still being alive, consider this example:

My dad is called John. I would say *John **is** my father*, and *I **am** the son of John*.

If my dad died, I would now say *John **was** my father*, but I would continue to say that *I **am** the son of John*, because I still exist, so *I am*.

If the parents in your example are dead but the children are still alive, the late parents still *have* surviving children. They *have* left them behind. Otherwise, saying "*they **had** a son*" could mean that they had one but he has since died.

Comment: Thanks. This is from the children's perspective. In my examples one or both parents are alive and I was curious about how to refer to them having / having had children.

Comment: I would find it very strange to say "my grandfather has three children" if my grandfather was, in fact, dead. His children still exist, but he does not - the grandfather doesn't currently *have* anything.

Comment: Like I said, this is not about English. The same issue exists in, say, Romance languages.

Comment: @Lambie: it is about English language because I want to understand how this works, grammatically speaking, in English. There could be differences such as between the related "had died" which is past tense in English and present tense in French, per our comments below the question. Anyway I have my answer (here and with FumbleFingers comment)

Comment: @WoJ You keep changing the goalposts. Now, you are saying "had died"? Il est mort.=He died, he has died or he **is dead**. Depending on context.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie But saying "my grandfather *had* three children" could sound like at least some of the children are dead. I'm not saying one thing always means this and another always means that - there are times when you'd have to qualify what you are saying. For example, "*my grandfather had three children and two of them are still alive*". But my answer stands - if you speak about the children in the present tense then it would mean they are alive.

Comment: Although Astralbee is right that *My grandfather **had** three children* **can** be interpreted to mean that some of his children have died, @NuclearHoagie is absolutely right that *My grandfather **has** three children* **does** mean—at least to this American—that he is still alive.